# React.js, issue with the React.create function

Tags: javascript, function

I need help with react.js. I keep receiving the same message error: React.render is not a function. I am not sure why. Below is my code:

I first thought that I had a browser issue and that react was not uploading on chrome, but the "hello world" div is not appearing on firefox too. Help would be much appreciated!

```
   <head>
<title> My First React File </title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js" </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
     <body>
     <script>
      React.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello World'),
      document.body);
      </script>
     </body>
```

Comment: React.render has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`React.render()` has been deprecated and you should now use `ReactDOM.render()`.

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('MyComponent'));
```